# Errors in PageRank of GraphFrames

Tags: pyspark, bigdata, apache-spark-sql, pagerank, graphframes

I am new to pyspark and am trying to understand how PageRank works. I am using Spark 1.6 in Jupyter on Cloudera. Screenshots of my vertices and edges (as well as the schema) are in these links: [verticesRDD](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vWJYc.png) and [edgesRDD](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mT3B8.png)

I have the code so far as follow:

```
#import relevant libraries for Graph Frames
from pyspark import SparkContext
from pyspark.sql import SQLContext
from pyspark.sql.functions import desc
from graphframes import *

#Read the csv files 
verticesRDD = sqlContext.read.format("com.databricks.spark.csv").options(header='true', inferschema='true').load("filepath/station.csv")
edgesRDD = sqlContext.read.format("com.databricks.spark.csv").options(header='true', inferschema='true').load("filepath/trip.csv")

#Renaming the id columns to enable GraphFrame 
verticesRDD = verticesRDD.withColumnRenamed("station_ID", "id")
edgesRDD = edgesRDD.withColumnRenamed("Trip ID", "id")
edgesRDD = edgesRDD.withColumnRenamed("Start Station", "src")
edgesRDD = edgesRDD.withColumnRenamed("End Station", "dst")

#Register as temporary tables for running the analysis
verticesRDD.registerTempTable("verticesRDD")
edgesRDD.registerTempTable("edgesRDD")
#Note: whether i register the RDDs as temp tables or not, i get the same results... so im not sure if this step is really needed

#Make the GraphFrame
g = GraphFrame(verticesRDD, edgesRDD)
```

Now when i run the pageRank function:

```
g.pageRank(resetProbability=0.15, maxIter=10)
```

Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o98.run.: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 79.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.0 in stage 79.0 (TID 2637, localhost): scala.MatchError: [null,null,[913460,765,8/31/2015 23:26,Harry Bridges Plaza (Ferry Building),50,8/31/2015 23:39,San Francisco Caltrain (Townsend at 4th),70,288,Subscriber,2139]] (of class org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GenericRowWithSchema)

```
results = g.pageRank(resetProbability=0.15, maxIter=10, sourceId="id")
```

Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o166.run.: org.graphframes.NoSuchVertexException: GraphFrame algorithm given vertex ID which does not exist in Graph. Vertex ID id not contained in GraphFrame(v:[id: int, name: string, lat: double, long: double, dockcount: int, landmark: string, installation: string], e:[src: string, dst: string, id: int, Duration: int, Start Date: string, Start Terminal: int, End Date: string, End Terminal: int, Bike #: int, Subscriber Type: string, Zip Code: string])

```
ranks = g.pageRank.resetProbability(0.15).maxIter(10).run()
```

AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'resetProbability'

```
ranks = g.pageRank(resetProbability=0.15, maxIter=10).run()
```

Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o188.run.: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 90.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.0 in stage 90.0 (TID 2641, localhost): scala.MatchError: [null,null,[913460,765,8/31/2015 23:26,Harry Bridges Plaza (Ferry Building),50,8/31/2015 23:39,San Francisco Caltrain (Townsend at 4th),70,288,Subscriber,2139]] (of class org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GenericRowWithSchema)

I am reading [PageRank](https://graphframes.github.io/user-guide.html#pagerank) but dont understand where i'm going wrong.. any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

The problem was how I was defining my vertices. I was renaming "station_id" to "id", when in fact, it had to be "name. So this line

```
verticesRDD = verticesRDD.withColumnRenamed("station_ID", "id")
```

has to be

```
verticesRDD = verticesRDD.withColumnRenamed("name", "id")
```

pageRank working properly with this change!